# Dealing with 301 redirects for a brand new website

Tags: redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I have seen multiple articles on redirecting Urls when the site has been redesigned or Url just changed to a standard format but I need to know how to manage when the Url has no correlation to the old one.

For instance, an old Url may have been `www.mysite.com/index.php?product=12` but there is no way to map that Url to the new site.

I don't want search engines to think that the page has broken so I assume the best thing to do is to 301 redirect to the home page but I am not sure how I would do that effectively. Would I just change the 404 error page to do a 301 to the home page?
Also, would that then cause issues with duplicate content via dofferent Urls?

Is it better to just not worry about these and let the search engines re-index the new Urls?

I am running IIS7 with Rewrite module and ASP.NET 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Apologies if this is in the wrong site, please direct me to the correct one if you are opting for me to close it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say there is no way to map that URL to the new one? There probably is, since both should be unique identifiers for a given resource. If your site has good rankings, it may be worth the pain to work this out and have a 301 redirect to the right page. In this way, the ranks should be unchanged.

Redirecting everything to the new home page will probably have a negative effect. It really depends on how the bots are going to interpret this. But it may seem an artificial way to increase the rank of the home page, and correspondingly get a penalty.

Doing nothing and waiting for the bots to index your new site will of course work, but often you cannot afford to lose the high rank you have gained.

All in all, I would advise you to ask here a new question on how to map the old URLs to the new ones, and do proper redirects.

Comment: Ok, I will put some thought into the redirection. The problem is that the customer may have changed all the codes for the stock items as well, that is why I think direct 301 redirects may not be possible. You answer sums it up well enough though and confirms my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

That product URL you supplied is obviously, well, a product. The best bet is to 301 redirect it to a new page that is the most relevant to that old page. If there aren't any external links even pointing to it at all, just let it die. Be sure to remove it from any sitemaps or old navigation links you may have internally though or it will keep getting re-indexed which is what you want to avoid.

Once you have your new site structure set up, visit a site like AuditMyPc.com and create a brand new sitemap of your new site setup. Then login to Google Webmaster Tools and resubmit the new sitemap. This normally will fix the problem, but if that page is indexed, expect it to stay in Google's index for a while. They don't clean themselves up too well.